# get_option() and update_option() in a transaction (for an autoincrement value)

Tags: options

I need an autoincremented ID for a custom post type to manage order IDs. For this, I would use the [WP Options API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/options-api), but I'm afraid of a typical transaction issue:

```
$count = get_option('my_id');
update_option('my_id', $count + 1);
```

When there is running a parallel request, `$count` could be the same value in both requests.

So: Is it somehow possible to set this code part as a transaction to prevent this issue?

**Edit**: Example scenario for a failed autoincrement:
If two users hit at the exact time time the process, where the code above will be executed, this may happen:

```
user 1: $count = get_option('my_id') // $count = 1
user 2: $count = get_option('my_id') // $count = 1
user 1: update_option('my_id', $count + 1); // 'my_id' = 2
user 2: update_option('my_id', $count + 1); // 'my_id' = 2
```

In a transaction, the database would wait for user 1 to get **and** update the value for 'my_id'. When user 1 finished the transaction process, user 2 would get the correct updated value.

Comment: Hello, I think there's not enough context to give you advices. Do you mean if a visitor hit an action at the exact same seconds, the `$count` may be wrongly updated ?

Comment: @SébastienSerre exactly. I added a failing example

Comment: note that `get_option` may never hit the database, it may be cached or stored in an object cache such as Redis/MemcacheD/etc. The options API is too high level to ask this. Infact the option may have been auto-loaded at the beginning of the request, so `get_option` may not query the DB even if the DB gets queried because WP batch fetched them all at once for performance reasons

Comment: Can you add more context for what the auto-incrementing is for and why it's needed? As well as why you chose options as the solution to the original problem?

Comment: My plugin creates internal posts (CPT) and needs an incrementing value for order IDs.